# How can i add visual feedback to react-simple-keyboard that will help confirm a key is pressed, like the magnified keys appearing in iOS?

Tags: reactjs, virtual-keyboard, react-simple-keyboard

React simple keyboard is amazing out of the box, and has many advantages over native mobile os keyboards. But, I miss the visual feedback you get in iOS when you tap a letter and it magnifies momentarily to confirm it was pressed. I can’t see how to pinpoint where in space the keys are with react simple keyboard, so implementing this seems like it would be very difficult. Has anyone tried to do this? Am I missing a simple solution?

Haven’t tried it yet, seems very difficult!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To add "feedback" you can simply add the :active property in CSS to your buttons to handle a different styling when a button is pressed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).